# ADA and reasonable accommodations

Tags: united-states, software, employment, discrimination, disabilities

https://www.eeoc.gov/facts/jobapplicant.html

Q: Is it a reasonable accommodation to request to remove all the oral interviews for a candidate programmer who has, for instance, social phobia? Or the requirement to allow her to work mostly from home?

Q: How the difference between essential and non-essential job function is determined? For instance, can the employer say that the ability to work under pressure is essential for the job? (given that this position is for a programmer rather than an air traffic controller)

Comment: This is pretty much a facts and circumstances question. It depends upon the nature of the disability and the nature of the job. There are a lot of programming jobs for which interacting in person is an essential job requirement, but perhaps not all of them.

Comment: @ohwilleke i.e. the question is - how does the law define what is an essential job requirement and what is not?

Comment: @user855286 As I understand it, the law does not define what is an "essential function" in any detail, leaving it to a court to rule if something is or is not when a specific case comes up.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that there are some programming projects where a program is created entirely from written specifications with no in-person interaction at all. That is not the most common situation, but it does happen, particularly in short-term consulting situations.

Comment: @David Siegel in your opinion, is it a reasonable accommodation to communicate in writing instead of in person?

Comment: @user855286, in my opinion, that depends very much on the details of the situation, and of the prospective job.  Note that an employer need not provide he specific accommodation requested, merely one which will reasonably accomodate the particular disability which the applicant or employee has.  Would communicating orally by telephone work for such a person, for example? How about by a real-time messenger app such as Skype? There are various possibilities.

Comment: @David Siegel I can't speak for everyone, but for me phone communication is even worse than in-person. Text messenger is perfectly fine.